# Firebase angularfire2 - How to return data from the current user only?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to figure out how to limit a collection to returning just the user's data, not everyone's data.

In the example I'm working from the FirebaseService only shows CRUD examples where the data that's returned is everything.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public platform: Platform
  ){}

  getEvents(){
      return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.afs.collection('/events').snapshotChanges() // add +auth.uid ... or something?
        .subscribe(snapshots => {
          resolve(snapshots)
        })
      })
    }

...
```

In order to only get the user's events back, I *think* I need to add:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

... and, do something from there. But, I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are documents in `/events` related to a user? For example: do they have a field that identifies the user? It might be easiest to see this if you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document in the collection.

Comment: It's an app where people keep a log of daily events relating to a medical question. So, they might log '9am ate breakfast' and '10:30 got a migraine' - which, is shown to them on a list. They should see their own events, but not everyone in the system. The first screen shot here [shows it](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1364291643) - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can limit this by adding rules. For example, you are using /users/ node to store user information. You can restrict only for the logged in user matching with userId can access /users/

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow get: if isSignedIn()
        && isOwner(userId);
     ....
    }

}
```

To get User Id

```
constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth  )

// then
ngOnInit() {

this.afAuth.authState;
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
      user => {
        this.userInfo = user; <-- You can store user Id information to user variable
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
}
```

**you can use this.userInfo.uid to make further calls.**